# What should I use instead of delaysig?

Tags: matlab

I'm using delaysig function in Matlab, but there is a warning saying:

Warning: DELAYSIG is an obsolete function.

I can actually keep using it, but there's no help file of delaysig on Matlab Documentation, so I need to find a new fucntion.

Comment: Perhaps just use the code from [here](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/nnet/nnobsolete/delaysig.m) to define a function that does the same, without the warning

Comment: maybe use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5943-generic-signal-class/content/delay.m).

Comment: Thank you, the both answers seem works properly, I do not search for a new function anymore, because I can't see any reason to change delaysig.